# AWK: Derive fields (create new columns) based on existing columns

Tags: awk

I have a `|` delimited file where each name in `$1` is assigned to a group in `$6`. The file is sorted based on `$5`(ascending order).

```
name_1|2018-09-28|1801-01-01|22|2018-11-19|group2117
name_1|2018-11-28|2018-11-28|81|2018-11-28|group1179
name_1|2018-09-28|2018-12-18|22|2018-12-14|group2117
name_4|2019-10-09|1801-01-01|22|2019-10-14|group3090
name_4|2019-10-09|2019-10-18|22|2019-10-15|group3090
name_4|2019-10-20|1801-01-01|21|2019-10-20|group3147
name_4|2019-10-20|2019-10-22|21|2019-10-21|group3147
name_11|2020-05-05|1801-01-01|21|2020-05-08|group4457
name_11|2020-05-05|2020-05-18|21|2020-05-18|group4457
```

I am trying to add some extra columns to this file based on the existing columns.

For the first appearance of each group in `$6`, I would like to take the corresponding values from `$2` and `$4` and add it to `$7` and `$8`, respectively. And for the last appearance of each group in `$6`, take the corresponding values from `$3` and add it to `$9`. so the output looks like this

```
name_1|2018-09-28|1801-01-01|22|2018-11-19|group2117|2018-09-28|22|2018-12-18
name_1|2018-11-28|2018-11-28|81|2018-11-28|group1179|2018-11-28|81|2018-11-28
name_1|2018-09-28|2018-12-18|22|2018-12-14|group2117|
name_4|2019-10-09|1801-01-01|22|2019-10-14|group3090|2019-10-09|22|2019-10-18
name_4|2019-10-09|2019-10-18|22|2019-10-15|group3090|
name_4|2019-10-20|1801-01-01|21|2019-10-20|group3147|2019-10-20|21|2019-10-22
name_4|2019-10-20|2019-10-22|21|2019-10-21|group3147|
name_11|2020-05-05|1801-01-01|21|2020-05-08|group4457|2020-05-05|21|2020-05-18
name_11|2020-05-05|2020-05-18|21|2020-05-18|group4457|
```

For just one group in `$6` I thought I can apply the below code but I am not sure how to adopt it for the outcome that I want

```
 awk -F"|" 'NR==1 {if($6==group1179); print $0,$7=$2,$8=$4,$9=$3}' OFS="|" file
```

output

```
name_1|2018-11-28|2018-11-28|81|2018-11-28|group1179|2018-11-28|81|2018-11-28
```

Please accept my apologies for the complicated sample input. Any lead on this will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sort -t'|' -k6,6 -k5,5 "${@:--}" |
awk '
    BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
    $6 != prev {
        if ( NR > 1 ) {
            prt()
        }
        prev = $6
    }
    { lines[++numLines] = $0 }
    END { prt() }

    function prt(       first,last,i) {
        split(lines[1],first)
        split(lines[numLines],last)

        print lines[1], first[2], first[4], last[3]

        for (i=2; i<=numLines; i++) {
            print lines[i]
        }

        numLines = 0
    }
' |
sort -t'|' -k5,5
```

```
$ ./tst.sh file
name_1|2018-09-28|1801-01-01|22|2018-11-19|group2117|2018-09-28|22|2018-12-18
name_1|2018-11-28|2018-11-28|81|2018-11-28|group1179|2018-11-28|81|2018-11-28
name_1|2018-09-28|2018-12-18|22|2018-12-14|group2117
name_4|2019-10-09|1801-01-01|22|2019-10-14|group3090|2019-10-09|22|2019-10-18
name_4|2019-10-09|2019-10-18|22|2019-10-15|group3090
name_4|2019-10-20|1801-01-01|21|2019-10-20|group3147|2019-10-20|21|2019-10-22
name_4|2019-10-20|2019-10-22|21|2019-10-21|group3147
name_11|2020-05-05|1801-01-01|21|2020-05-08|group4457|2020-05-05|21|2020-05-18
name_11|2020-05-05|2020-05-18|21|2020-05-18|group4457
```

Comment: Hi Ed Morton, I have a quick question - For the last appearance of each group in `$6`, if I want to take the corresponding values from any other column and add it to `$10` or `$11`, how can I edit your code?

Comment: Do exactly the same thing I do for the 3rd column. Try it - you'll almost certainly get it right first time as it's extremely clear and obvious IMHO.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is a two-pass approach where you capture the last instance of each group on the first pass and write the data out on the second, e.g.

```
awk -F"|" -v OFS="|" '
    NR==FNR { last[$6] = $3; next }
    $6 in seen { print; next }
    { print $0, $2, $4, last[$6]; seen[$6]++ }
' file file
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
name_1|2018-09-28|1801-01-01|22|2018-11-19|group2117|2018-09-28|22|2018-12-18
name_1|2018-11-28|2018-11-28|81|2018-11-28|group1179|2018-11-28|81|2018-11-28
name_1|2018-09-28|2018-12-18|22|2018-12-14|group2117
name_4|2019-10-09|1801-01-01|22|2019-10-14|group3090|2019-10-09|22|2019-10-18
name_4|2019-10-09|2019-10-18|22|2019-10-15|group3090
name_4|2019-10-20|1801-01-01|21|2019-10-20|group3147|2019-10-20|21|2019-10-22
name_4|2019-10-20|2019-10-22|21|2019-10-21|group3147
name_11|2020-05-05|1801-01-01|21|2020-05-08|group4457|2020-05-05|21|2020-05-18
name_11|2020-05-05|2020-05-18|21|2020-05-18|group4457
```

Comment: Hi David C. Rankin, it worked. thank you very much for your help. Much appreciated.

Comment: Glad to help. `awk` is the Swiss Army-Knife of text processing, and there is usually more than one way to make it work. Good luck with your scripting.

Comment: Thank you. "awk is the Swiss Army-Knife of text processing" -  would be my new favourite quote now :)

Comment: Hi David C. Rankin,  I have a quick question - For the last appearance of each group in `$6`, if I want to take the corresponding values from any other column and add it to `$10` or `$11`, how can I edit your code?

Comment: Just use another array. I just used `last` for the last occurrence of `$3`. You could change that to `last3` and then add a `last5` array (e.g. for last occurrence of `$5`) if you wanted. Then just add it to the output.

Comment: Thank you @David C. Rankin. Is this the right way in case I want to take the `$5` value for the last appearance? `awk -F"|" -v OFS="|" ' NR==FNR { last3[$6] = $3;last5[$6]=$5; next } $6 in seen { print; next } { print $0, $2, $4, last3[$6],last5[$6]; seen[$6]++ }'` file file

Comment: Yes! Good job. That should work just fine.

Answer (score 4):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`, should work in any version of `awk`.

```
awk '
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="|" }
!arr1[$6]++{
  arr4[++count]=$6
}
{
  lastVal[$6]=$3
  ++arr3[$6]
  arr2[arr3[$6],$6]=$0
  arr5[arr3[$6],$6]=$2 OFS $4
}
END{
  for(i=1;i<=count;i++){
    for(j=1;j<=arr3[arr4[i]];j++){
      print arr2[arr3[arr4[i]],arr4[i]],(j==1?arr5[arr3[arr4[i]],arr4[i]]:"") (j==1?OFS lastVal[arr4[i]]:"")
    }
  }
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: its late night here, will try to add explanation in early morning or so, cheers.

Comment: Good approach, but you are missing appending `$2` from the first instance and then `$3` from the last occurrence of `$6`. I'm sure you can work your magic and make them appear `:)`

Comment: Hi RavinderSingh13, thank you very much for the answer. I will try it on the input file. Thank you for your time. much appreciated.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, Thanks sir for letting know, its been fixed now, cheers.

Comment: Hi RavinderSingh13, thank you. I would like to upvote your question but I have not been able to implement it on the input file. For Ed's answer I just saved it as a .sh script and managed to run it. David's answer was a one-liner so I managed to run it. Should I save your answer as an .awk script and run it on the file? Thank you.

Comment: Works fine now @RavinderSingh13 - your magic is certainly powerful...

Comment: @D_Stack_overflow, run it either directly on terminal on your box, place actual file name in place of Input_file name. If you want to run it as a script then copy/paste complete code in bash/sh script and pass your actual file name in it and run it then. Either of these 2 ways should work. Cheers

Comment: @ RavinderSingh13, thank you it worked and I have upvoted your question. Could I please ask  - For the last appearance of each group in `$6`, if I want to take the corresponding values from any other column and add it to `$10` or `$11`, how can I edit your code?

Comment: @D_Stack_overflow, could you please give an example here(don't change your question now as it will confuse future users), just explain it here and I could try to help, cheers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13, no worries. I managed to solve it with help from David C. Rankin.  Thanks.